# The swipe to delete animation does not work in IOS 11

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am `overridng` `editActionsForRow` method to create a custom delete button in `iOS 11` when user swipes to delete the row. Deletion works but the row does not move all the way to left during the animation process. Note, I have specified delete row animation style to left. Despite that it still does not work.

In one of the forums it has been mentioned as a bug in `iOS 11`. Any thoughts on this.

Below is the code snippet

```
public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {

    var actionHide = UITableViewRowAction.Create(UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, "Hide for now".Localize(),  (arg1, arg2) => {

    // delete the row from the table source and UITableView
    GroupedChallenge[indexPath.Section].RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
    tableView.DeleteRows(rows, UITableViewRowAnimation.Left);                                                                 
});
    actionHide.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
    return new UITableViewRowAction[] { actionHide };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code to show how you're attempting to implement this?

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: Did you debug your project in iOS 10 or 9?   UITableViewRowAnimation.Left only works on the cell ,it can not  set the delete button.

Comment: I solved it using tableView.PerformBatchUpdates